# Azure media player does not work if "azuremediaplayer.min.js" is not included in the file

Tags: azure, azure-media-services, azure-media-player

I am trying to integrate azure media player in my android app.

It didn't work what I pass manifest url to `videoView` along with `.ism/manifest(format=m3u8-aapl-v3)`

So I decided to play it on chrome for testing.

The issue is video does not work if i comment out following `<script>` tag

```
 <script src="https://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/latest/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

If this script is there, it works just fine.

Now my questions is that, when there is no android SDK available for Azure media player, how it will work on android when it does not work in browser without `<script>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are building a native Android application, you would typically use a more native player framework like ExoPlayer.

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer

When using ExoPlayer, you can then use either the HLS or DASH manifest URL from Media Services.

Comment: Thanks, how can i be sure if backend team provided me HLS or DASH mainfest URL, any difference in the URL, currently i am getting something like this `https://test.domain.media.azure.net/11111-11-1111-111-111/VideoName_1.ism/manifest`

Comment: and yes i tried it on Exo player, but it didn't work

Comment: That looks like the default URL - if you curl that, you should see a Smooth Streaming XML manifest. 
To get the packager to return back HLS - you add /manifest(format=m3u8-aapl) - this will give you back HLS v4 with TS packaged chunks.
To get the latest CMAF (MP4) based version of HLS (v7+) you would use - /manifest(format=m3u8-cmaf)

See here for details on packager - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/dynamic-packaging-overview#hls-protocol

Comment: Dash packager URL format strings here - 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/media-services/latest/dynamic-packaging-overview#mpeg-dash-protocol

Comment: also make sure to add either the full ExoPlayer or the specific dependency module 
exoplayer-core: Core functionality (required).
exoplayer-dash: Support for DASH content.
exoplayer-hls: Support for HLS content.

Comment: Thank you so much !!! :) When i added "(format=mpd-time-csf)" it worked on exo player :)